# Class not printing entire variable

Tags: python, class

I am failry new to coding so I've been trying to figure out how to get the entire output variable to print to the terminal. Right now the first 5 methods print when I print self.output with an instance of Change maker as gregs_vending_machine.

Notes: The round method is going to cause my numbers to get thrown off when I get to the pennies so my plan is to multiply change due by 100 and go from there.

Once I solve the way above I will refactor to solve with one method utilizing a global class dictionary for my values.

Code is Below:

```
   class ChangeMaker:
    def __init__(self, total_price, amount_paid):
        self.total_price = total_price
        self.amount_paid = amount_paid
        self.change_due= self.change(self.total_price,self.amount_paid)
        self.output = (f'For an item that costs ${self.total_price} with an amount paid of ${self.amount_paid} your change due is ${self.change_due}. Given in{self.hundreds_sentence_generator()}{self.fifties_sentence_generator()}{self.twenties_sentence_generator()}{self.tens_sentence_generator()}{self.fives_sentence_generator()}{self.dollars_sentence_generator()}\n{self.quarters_sentence_generator()}{self.dimes_sentence_generator()}{self.nickels_sentence_generator()}{self.pennies_sentence_generator()}')
        self.change_output = (f'{self.quarters_sentence_generator()}{self.dimes_sentence_generator()}{self.nickels_sentence_generator()}{self.pennies_sentence_generator()}') def change(self, total_price, amount_paid):
        return round(int(amount_paid) - int(total_price),2)

    def hundreds_sentence_generator(self):
      hundreds_due= self.change_due//round(100.00,2)
      self.change_due -= round(100.00,2) * hundreds_due
      if hundreds_due == 1:
        return f' {int(hundreds_due)}: $100 Bill, '
      elif hundreds_due > 1:
        return f' {int(hundreds_due)}: $100 Bills, '
      else:
        return ""


    def fifties_sentence_generator(self):
      fifties_due= self.change_due//round(50.00,2)
      self.change_due -= round(50.00,2) * fifties_due
      if fifties_due == 1:
        return f'{int(fifties_due)}: $50 Bill, '
      elif fifties_due > 1:
        return f'{int(fifties_due)}: $50 Bills, '
      else:
        return ""

    def twenties_sentence_generator(self):
      twenties_due= self.change_due//round(20.00,2)
      self.change_due -= round(20.00,2) * twenties_due
      if twenties_due == 1:
        return f'{int(twenties_due)}: $20 Bill, '
      elif twenties_due > 1:
        return f'{int(twenties_due)}: $20 Bills, '
      else:
        return ""

    def tens_sentence_generator(self):
      tens_due= self.change_due//round(10.00,2)
      self.change_due -= round(10.00,2) * tens_due
      if tens_due == 1:
        return f'{int(tens_due)}: $10 Bill, '
      elif tens_due > 1:
        return f'{int(tens_due)}: $10 Bills, '
      else:
        return ""

    def fives_sentence_generator(self):
      fives_due= self.change_due//round(5.00,2)
      self.change_due -= round(5.00,2) * fives_due
      if fives_due == 1:
        return f'{int(fives_due)}: $5 Bill, '
      else:
        return ""

    def dollars_sentence_generator(self):
      dollars_due= self.change_due//round(1.00,2)
      self.change_due -= round(1.00,2) * dollars_due
      if dollars_due == 1:
        return f'{int(dollars_due)}: $1 Bill, '
      elif dollars_due > 1:
        return f'{int(dollars_due)}: dollars, '
      else:
        return ""

    def quarters_sentence_generator(self):
      quarters_due= self.change_due//round(0.25,2)
      self.change_due -= round(0.25,2) * quarters_due
      if quarters_due == 1:
        return f'{int(quarters_due)}: Quarter, '
      elif quarters_due > 1:
        return f'{int(quarters_due)}: Quarters, '
      else:
        return ""

    def dimes_sentence_generator(self):
      dimes_due= self.change_due//round(0.10,2)
      self.change_due -= round(0.10,2) * dimes_due
      if dimes_due == 1:
        return f'{int(dimes_due)}: Dime, '
      elif dimes_due > 1:
        return f'{int(dimes_due)}: Dimes, '
      else:
        return ""

    def nickels_sentence_generator(self):
      nickels_due= self.change_due//round(0.05,4)
      self.change_due -= round(0.05,2) * nickels_due
      if nickels_due == 1:
        return f'{int(nickels_due)}: Nickel, '
      else:
        return ""

    def pennies_sentence_generator(self):
      if self.change_due == round(0.01,2):
        return f'1: Penny, '
      elif self.change_due > round(0.01,2):
        return f'{int(self.change_due*100)}: Pennies, '
      else:
        return ""

gregs_vending_machine = ChangeMaker(1.01, 190.88)
print(gregs_vending_machine.output)''
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to print? what is an example of the output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I answered below, please feel free to comment on the answer if the solution does not work. I know sometimes time is tight, but when you have a chance you might want to look at the following guidelines on how to submit a "good" question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and link to the article. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.change()` method is using `int`, so your `change_due` will never include any coins. So just change your `self.change()` to:

```
def change(self, total_price, amount_paid):
    return amount_paid - total_price
```

and I think it will all work.

Comment: Thanks that was one of the mistakes I made . Ended up solving the challenge at the end of the day. Not happy with how I solved or how long it took me but at least it's progress. Thanks for the help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue may be that you are casting `amount_paid` and `total_price` as integers. This will cause decimals to be truncated. If I change your `change` method to the following, I seem to get correct results.

```
def change(self, total_price, amount_paid):
    return round(amount_paid - total_price, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks that was one of the mistakes I made . Ended up solving the challenge at the end of the day. Not happy with how I solved or how long it took me but at least it's progress. Thanks for the help much appreciated